What could be the reason why the kokuji 働 exists?
The etymology of the kokuji 働 seems straightforward enough, 動 plus the radical 亻. What's not straightforward is why the Japanese felt the need to create it. I could think of at least three hypotheses:

There was a need to spell the verb はたらく. The sense development of はたらく seems to be similar to the Chinese 動: "move" > "act" > "act on something" > "work" ("move" is not a common sense for はたらく, but recorded in certain dictionaries like Daijisen and Daijirin). However, spelling はたらく with the same kanji as うごく may be unhelpful because they're both yodan/godan verbs. So whoever created 働 might have felt the need to distinguish はたらく from うごく, which ended up being the case now that はたらく predominantly means "work" and うごく "move".
The literal meaning of the Chinese 勞動 ("tiring movement/action") wasn't felt as strongly as its surface meaning, "toil", and probably since はたらく had already been spelt with 働, it just made sense to spell that Chinese word with 勞働 instead (and of course in shinjitai, 労働).
In most compounds with 働 (労働, 稼働, 共働, 実働, 複働, 協働), the emphasis is more on proactive "work" or "act", rather than passive or reactive "move" alone. The human radical 亻 may have been intended to make human agency clearer. The distinction between "work/act" and "move" was useful, it was just that the Japanese found it more useful than the Chinese did.

So what could be the reason(s) for why the Japanese feel the need to create 働?

a quick search yields this https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1492239914

@aka If 働 was created that recently in the Meiji era, maybe there's a chance someone could trace it back to its first attestation and its coiner.

One thing I have to correct you: 労働 is actually a Japan-made Kanji compound that got re-imported back into Chinese. Because 働 is a Japanese-made Kanji, the Chinese decided to spell 労働 with 動 in the Chinese language

@dvx2718 You're very wrong about that. 勞動 is attested in Zhuangzi and Romance of the Three Kingdoms. Even Wiktionary editors know how old it is.

@Vun-HughVaw I got my info on the Chinese site of 搜狐, if I am wrong then they're also wrong then ‍♂️

@dvx2718 I don't know what that website's about, but here's a quote from Zhuangzi: 春耕種, 形足以勞動; 秋收斂, 身足以休息. And here's a quote from Romance of the Three Kingdoms: 人体欲得勞動，但不當使极耳. I got this quote from the 汉语外来词词典. The word 勞動 is not a Japanese coinage, the spelling 勞働 is. That you cited a bad source doesn't mean anything.

@dvx2718 Hmm, apparently you didn't read your source, which is the same as mine, the 汉语外来词词典, correctly. It says that 勞動 was borrowed from Japanese, which repurposed an "ancient Chinese" compound (古代漢語), or more accurately Middle Chinese and Classical Chinese. That was common practice during the Meiji period in case you didn't know. This source does get some things wrong, for example it misattributes 神経 to Classical Chinese sources, although the meaning in those sources has nothing to do with its modern meaning and the identical spelling is a mere coincidence.

Are we actually sure that 働 was invented in Japan? Because in a Dūnhuáng manuscript called 大乘起信論廣釋 (T2814, Extensive Commentary to Treatise on Awakening Mahāyāna Faith) by 曇曠 Tánkuàng (700-788) of Tang he defines 端坐 "sitting upright" as follows: 言端坐者。是顯調身。身若僵仆或彼働側前復依倚左右憑附既生懈怠。
Something like that: "The term 端坐, 'sitting upright', refers to explicitly harmonizing your body. Were the body stiff, or it 働 to the sides and back, leaning on the left and right, this begets laxity."
It seems clear that 働 is used in the meaning of 動, to move, probably with 働 emphasizing movement of a human, and yet this is a confirmation that 働 was indeed used in medieval China. So the character could have been imported as a variant of 動 and simply was standardized differently in Japan, in two characters for two meanings.
There are more 働 in Yuan and Ming, but they are clear miswritings for 慟.

Interesting. I just took for granted the oft-repeated claim that 働 is a kokuji.
